# What faster way is there when counting occurrences of elements in one using another list

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

If I have two lists, `List_A` and `List_B` what faster way is there if I want to count the number of occurrences of each element in `List_B` from `List_A` and parse the results in a new `List_C`?
Usually Id use list comprehension but once the number of elements in either `List_A` or `List_B` increase above 100 000 it starts taking quite a lot of time.

```js
List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']

List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

List_C = [List_A.count(x) for x in List_B]

List_C

#Output:

#List_C = [3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: If `List_A` doesn't change very often, but your program keeps getting new data in a `List_B`, you could use `Counter` to precalculate the values instead of having to call `.count(x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def a():
    List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
    List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'z']

    count = Counter(List_A)
    List_C = [count.get(x) for x in List_B]
```

100000 loops, best of 5: 2.96 usec per loop

---

Using Counter() and checking for None:

```
def b():
    List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
    List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'z']

    count = Counter(List_A)

    List_C = []

    for x in List_B:
        val = count.get(x)
        if val != None:
            List_C.append(val)
```

100000 loops, best of 5: 3.45 usec per loop

---

Without checking None values:

```
def c():
    List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
    List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'z']

    count = Counter(List_A)

    List_C = []

    for x in List_B:
        List_C.append(count.get(x))
```

100000 loops, best of 5: 3.04 usec per loop

---

Using @Mafa's solution, which doesn't work if List_B have values that don't appear in List_A:

```
def d():
    List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
    List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    occ = dict()
    for x in List_A:
        occ.setdefault(x, 0)
        occ[x] += 1
    List_C = [occ[x] for x in List_B]
```

100000 loops, best of 5: 2.59 usec per

---

Mafa's Solution with checks for existing values:

```
def e():
    List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
    List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    occ = dict()
    for x in List_A:
        occ.setdefault(x, 0)
        occ[x] += 1
    List_C = [occ.get(x, 0) for x in List_B]
```

100000 loops, best of 5: 3.1 usec per loop

---

The two next functions were proposed by @Alex Waygood

```
def f():
    List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
    List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    c = Counter(filter(set(List_B).__contains__, List_A))
    List_C = [v for k, v in sorted(c.items())]
```

50000 loops, best of 5: 4.45 usec per loop

---

```
def g():
    List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
    List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'z']
    c = Counter(filter(List_B.__contains__, List_A))
    List_C = [v for k, v in sorted(c.items())]
```

50000 loops, best of 5: 4.78 usec per loop

(Not sure if need to divide by two here -- apparently not --, since there are 50000 loops instead of 100000, if that is the case we have a clear winner here)

Comment: It's measured per-loop, so division by two shouldn't be necessary. Could you maybe try my one with it as `c = Counter(filter(List_B.__contains__, List_A))` instead of `c = Counter(filter(set(List_B).__contains__, List_A))`? I'd be interested to see if that's any faster or slower.

Comment: Also do bear in mind that we're measuring with *tiny* lists here, and it could well be that the comparison would look very different with much longer lists. It's often the case that algorithms that perform best in class on very small sequences will be catastrophic for much longer ones.

Comment: The test in `[occ[x] for x in List_B if x in List_B]` does not make sense: it always evaluates to `True`.  The list should instead be: `[occ.get(x, 0) for x in List_B]`.

Comment: There is a ' missing in line 2 of function `f` (just before `d`).

Comment: @qouify indeed, it's now fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

With your solution you perform a number of computations equal to `len(List_A) * len(List_B)` (your list comprehension).

Instead, first compute the number of occurences then do your list comprehension:

```py
List_A = ['a', 'd','f','h','g','e','f','a','f','h','h','d','b','c','c','a']
List_B = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
occ = dict()
for x in List_A:
    occ.setdefault(x, 0)
    occ[x] += 1
List_C = [occ.get(x, 0) for x in List_B]
```

By this way you traverse `List_A` once and `List_B` once.

[Edit]

Updated the list comprehension at last line to address the case where `x` is not in `List_A` (see @AchilleG's comment)